# OpenGL ES - iPhone4 - fragment shader variables count

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, glsl

I have high number of variables (30 uniforms (mostly vec4), about 20 variables (vec3, float, vec4) within shader) within fragment shader. It runs just fine on iPhone5S, but I have serious problem on iPhone4. GPU time is 1s / frame and 98% of the time is shader run time.

According to Apple [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH7-SW3)

> OpenGL ES limits the number of each variable type you can use in a
>   vertex or fragment shader. The OpenGL ES specification doesn’t require
>   implementations to provide a software fallback when these limits are
>   exceeded; instead, the shader simply fails to compile or link. When
>   developing your app you must ensure that no errors occur during shader
>   compilation, as shown in Listing 10-1.

But from this I quite dont understand. Do they provide SW fallback or not? Because I have no errors during compilation or linking of shader and yet performance is poor. I have comment almost everything out and just leave 2 texture lookups and directional light computation. I changed other functions to return just vec4(0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 1):

The limitation on uniforms is much higher than that. GLSL ES (2.0) requires 512 scalar uniform components per-vertex shader (though ES describes this in terms of the number of vectors -- 128). Assuming all 30 of your uniforms were `vec4`, you still have enough storage for 98 more.

The relevant limits are `gl_MaxVertexUniformVectors` and `gl_MaxFragmentUniformVectors`. Implementations are only required to support 16 in the fragment shader, but most will far exceed the minimum - check the values yourself. Query the limits from GL ES rather than trying to figure them out in your GLSL program with some Frankenstein shader code ;)

> #### [OpenGL ES 2.0 Shading Language](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) - Appendix A: Limitations - pp. 113
>
> ```c
> const mediump int gl_MaxVertexAttribs             = 8; 
> const mediump int gl_MaxVertexUniformVectors      = 128;
> const mediump int gl_MaxVaryingVectors            = 8; 
> const mediump int gl_MaxVertexTextureImageUnits   = 0; 
> const mediump int gl_MaxCombinedTextureImageUnits = 8;
> const mediump int gl_MaxTextureImageUnits         = 8; 
> const mediump int gl_MaxFragmentUniformVectors    = 16;
> const mediump int gl_MaxDrawBuffers               = 1;
> ```

In fact, it would be a good idea to query all of the GLSL program / shader limits just to get a better idea of the constraints you need to work under for your target software/hardware. It is better to plan ahead than to wait to address these things until your program blows up.

---

As for software fallbacks, I doubt it. This is an embedded environment, there is not much need for such a thing. When developing the actual software on a PC/Mac, they usually ship with a reference software implementation mostly for ***testing*** purposes. Individual components may sometimes fallback to software to overcome hardware limitations, but that is necessary because of the wide variety of hardware in Apple's Mac line alone. But when you are writing an app that is specifically written for a single specification of hardware it is generally acceptable to give a complete failure if you try to do something that exceeds the limitations (which you are expected to be familiar with).

Comment: By the way, literal constants in your GLSL program can count against uniform limits too. I know that sounds a bit weird, but if GL called uniforms the same thing as Direct3D does (constant buffers), it would probably make a little more sense. Any variable that is ***constant*** is basically a uniform.